# Are 3k kafka topics decrease performance?

Tags: apache-kafka, aiven

I have a Kafka Cluster (Using Aivan on AWS):

#### Kafka Hardware

```
Startup-2 (2 CPU, 2 GB RAM, 90 GB storage, no backups) 3-node high availability set
```

- Ping between my consumers and the Kafka Broker is 0.7ms.

#### Backgroup

I have a topic such that:

- It contains data about 3000 entities.
- Entity lifetime is a week.
- Each week there will be different 3000 entities (on avg).
- Each entity may have between 15k to 50k messages in total.
- There can be at most 500 messages per second.

###### Architecture

My team built an architecture such that there will be a group of consumers. They will parse this data, perform some transformations (without any filtering!!) and then **sends the final messages back to the kafka to `topic=<entity-id>`**.

It means I upload the data back to the kafka to a topic that contains only a data of a specific entity.

#### Questions

At any given time, there can be up to 3-4k topics in kafka (1 topic for each unique entity).

1. Can my kafka handle it well? If not, what do I need to change?
2. Do I need to delete a topic or it's fine to have (alot of!!) unused topics over time?
3. Each consumer which consumes the final messages, will consume 100 topics at the same time. I know kafka clients can consume multiple topics concurrenctly but I'm not sure what is the best practices for that.
4. Please share your concerns.

#### Requirements

- Please focus on the potential problems of this architecture and try not to talk about alternative architectures (less topics, more consumers, etc).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The number of topics is not so important in itself, but each Kafka topic is partitioned and the total number of partitions could impact performance.

The [general recommendation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=148641509) from the Apache Kafka community is to have no more than 4,000 partitions per broker (this includes replicas). The linked KIP article explains some of the possible issues you may face if the limit is breached, and with 3,000 topics it would be easy to do so unless you choose a low partition count and/or replication factor for each topic.

Choosing a low partition count for a topic is sometimes not a good idea, because it limits the parallelism of reads and writes, leading to performance bottlenecks for your clients.

Choosing a low replication factor for a topic is also sometimes not a good idea, because it increases the chance of data loss upon failure.

Generally it's fine to have unused topics on the cluster but be aware that there is still a performance impact for the cluster to manage the metadata for all these partitions and some operations will still take longer than if the topics were not there at all.

There is also a per-cluster limit but that is much higher (200,000 partitions). So your architecture might be better served simply by increasing the node count of your cluster.

Comment: Thanks. I don't need replicas and each topic (from the 3k topics) will only have 1 partition because there is only 1 producer and 1 consumer to and from this topic. If I will remove a topic after I know it is not used, will it decrease performance in the broker at the same time? I assume that I won't delete more than 1 topic at the same time window (1 minute +-). What do you think?

Comment: That all sounds fine so long as you don't care about the possibility of data loss, which is always a risk when topics have replication factor = 1.